# How to pass the id from view to controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass id from view to controller. I know how to pass it by assigning a name to it like : `:eid => @model["_id"]`. And then I can fetch in controller using `params[:"_id"]`.

But then the url would be `/create?:eid="1234"`. But I want this: `create/1234`. So how can I do that

1. In view
2. How to fetch in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should spend some time learning about routes. You'll need to define a route to do what you want to do.

In your `config/routes.rb`

```
match '/create/:eid' => 'underscored_name_of_controller_here#create', :as => :create
```

Then, in your view:

```
create_path(:eid => @model["_id"])
```

I'll also suggest that the path of your route probably ought to be more descriptive that just `/create/:_id` but in the spirit of answering your question I've left it as such.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a [custom route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), something like:

```
post "/create/:eid" => "my_controller#my_action"
```

That said, it's unusual to add route params to a create action. The typical method is just to add a hidden input to a form that submits to the action.